# Pyplot: subsequent plots with a gradient of colours

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, colors

So, I am creating a plot with a collection of curves that are basically the same function changing slightly a parameter (this is done in a for loop). The plot looks like this:

[Black-scholes call option prices at different times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1Tn3.png)

The question now is: is there any simple way of making pyplot plot each curve in some logical colour order instead of that random-looking order? Maybe there is a way of creating a list with colours in a gradient and pass it as argument to pyplot in the loop?

The code I have written looks like this:

```
#Parameters
K = 100
T = 1
r = 0.02
sigma = 0.2 

#Plotting
fig , ax = plt.subplots()
S = np.linspace(80,120,100)
for i in range(0,10):
    t = i/10
    V = black_scholes_call_price(S,t,K,T,r,sigma) #This is just a function of S with parameters
    ax.plot(S,V,label='t = {}'.format(t))
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Choose a [sequential colormap](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html). Address individual colors with `c=cm.thechosencolormap(i/n)` - and in your case i/n is `t`.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for!